# If I making a forum with CouchDB, how should I manage forum users?

Tags: couchdb, user-accounts

I'm learning CouchDB. If I make a forum with CouchDB, how should I manage (create/delete/update) forum user account?

Answer (score 3):

CouchDB has built-in user authentication and role-based authorization. Check out [this article](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html) to get you started down that path.